# ‎every ‎ring ‎automorphism‎ $\Phi$ ‎of ‎the ‎complex ‎algebra ‎‎

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Why ‎every ‎ring ‎automorphism‎ $‎\Phi$ ‎of ‎the ‎complex ‎algebra 
$‎‎M‎‎‎_{‎n‎} ‎(‎\mathbb{C}‎)$ 
‎of ‎all $‎n‎\times n$‎ ‎complex ‎matrices ‎has ‎the ‎form ‎‎
‎$\Phi ‎(T)= ‎AT‎A‎^{-1} ‎‎$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is (a special case, but not so special) of the [Skolem-Noether theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem).

$\def\CC{\mathbb C}$Suppose that $f:M_n(\CC)\to\ M_n(\CC)$ is an isomorphim of rings.

First, notice that the map $f$ has to restrict to an automorphism of the centr of $M_n(\CC)$, which is the subspace of scalar matrices, which we can identify with $\CC$. It follows that $f$ is in fact $\CC$-linear.

Let $V=\CC^n$ the vector space of column vectors. Then $V$ is a left $M_n(\CC)$-module in two ways. First, there is an action $$(A,v)\in M_n(\CC)\times V\longmapsto Av\in V$$ given simply by matrix multiplication. Second, there is an action given by $$(A,v)\in M_n(\CC)\times V\longmapsto f(A)v\in V$$. We denote $V_1$ and $V_2$ the two $M_n(\CC)$-module structures.

Now $M_n(\CC)$ is a simple artinian ring, so all its simple modules are isomorphic, and you can easily check that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are simple. It follows that there is an isomorphism $\phi:V_1\to V_2$. This isomorphism is $\CC$-linear, so it is given by an invertible matrix $A\in M_n(\CC)$.

I'll leave it for you to find the relation between the automorphism $f$ and the matrix $A$.